# Having issues making my card take full width using bootstrap grid system

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I have 3 price lists , right, all is good they look good, but when I am trying to style them for smaller screens where one card takes the full width of the col using bootstrap 5.3 grid system, it's not working as expected , I did col-12-lg  for one and col-lg-6 two the other two in no avail so idk anymore, help is appreciated, that being said here's the code

```css
/*section 4 styles start*/
.section4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: rgb(48, 49, 57);
  color: white;
}

.show-fade-in4 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInAnimation4 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation4 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(-30%);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
.show-fade-in5 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInAnimation5 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation5 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-30%);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
.show-fade-in6 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInAnimation6 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation6 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(30%);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
.show-fade-in7 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInAnimation7 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation7 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(30%);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(0);
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}

.containerStyle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.h5-section4 {
  color: orange;
}

.cards-container {
  padding: 40px 30px 52px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
}

.cardPriceStyle {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.card-Detail-Style {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.card-Button-Style {
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

.card-Button-Style:hover {
  background-color: rgb(184, 122, 6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .section4 {
    height: 190vh;
  }
}

/*section 4 styles end*/

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--bootsrap cdn-->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- local stylesheet link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" />

    <!-- home js local code-->
    <script defer src="home.js"></script>

    <!--my owl carousel css file-->

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <!-- my owl carousel css file2-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- my navbar start-->

    <section>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navStyle">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand fs-2" href="#">Empower Fitness</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler ms-auto"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ms-auto" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto align-items-end fs-3">
              <a
                class="nav-link active me-0 ms-5 navItems"
                aria-current="page"
                href="file:///C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/gym-app1/home/home.html"
                >Home</a
              >
              <a
                class="nav-link me-0 ms-5 navItems"
                href="file:///C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/gym-app1/aboutUs/abouUs.html"
                >About us
              </a>
              <a
                class="nav-link me-0 ms-5 navItems"
                href="file:///C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/gym-app1/service/service.html"
                >Service
              </a>
              <a
                class="nav-link me-0 ms-5 navItems"
                href="file:///C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Desktop/gym-app1/contactUs/contactUs.html"
                >Contact us
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <!--my navbar end-->

    <!-- section 1 start-->
    <section>
      <div class="section1">
        <div class="fade-in1">
          <div class="text-center containerStyle1">
            <p class="h1 mb-3 p-element1">WE ARE HERE TO HELP</p>
            <h1 class="mb-2 h1-element1">EMPOWER YOU FOR LIFE</h1>
            <p class="mb-3 p2-section1">
              ENHANCING HEALTH & <br />
              PERFORMANCE THROUGH <br />
              FITNESS, NUTRITION<br />
              & COMMUNITY.
            </p>

            <button class="shadow-lg button-element1" type="button">
              GET STARTED
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--section 2-->
    <section>
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="fade-in2">
          <div>
            <h4 class="pt-5 h4-element1">Why Choose us?</h4>
            <h2 class="p-2 mb-5 h2-element1">PUSH YOUR LIMITS FORWARD</h2>

            <div class="row text-center">
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xml:space="preserve"
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-miterlimit="2"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                  viewBox="0 0 100 126.25"
                  class="fontIconStyle"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="#f36100"
                    d="M79.035 27.349a3.92 3.92 0 0 1 3.919 3.92v7.895a20.507 20.507 0 0 1 15.037 19.763v.043a20.509 20.509 0 0 1-20.506 20.506h-6.853v7.755h10.5a6.09 6.09 0 0 1 6.09 6.091v.087a6.09 6.09 0 0 1-6.09 6.091H18.868a6.09 6.09 0 0 1-6.09-6.091v-.087a6.09 6.09 0 0 1 6.09-6.091h10.5v-7.755h-1.702c-.138.003-3.38.057-9.017-2.057-9.717-3.644-16.64-13.023-16.64-24.006 0-13.458 10.394-24.506 23.584-25.551v-3.697h3.92v3.684c7.78.563 14.601 4.603 18.913 10.572H63.07v-7.152a3.92 3.92 0 0 1 3.92-3.92h12.045ZM33.288 79.476v7.755h33.424v-7.755H33.288Zm1.949-17.182a11.48 11.48 0 0 1-7.596 2.86c-6.362 0-11.526-5.164-11.526-11.525 0-6.361 5.164-11.526 11.526-11.526 6.361 0 11.525 5.165 11.525 11.526a11.47 11.47 0 0 1-1.462 5.619l3.932 3.276h10.362a1.96 1.96 0 0 1 0 3.92H40.927c-.459 0-.903-.16-1.255-.454l-4.435-3.696Zm-.625-5.623a7.61 7.61 0 0 0-6.971-10.648 7.61 7.61 0 0 0-7.606 7.606 7.61 7.61 0 0 0 7.606 7.606 7.572 7.572 0 0 0 4.529-1.497l-5.784-4.82a1.96 1.96 0 0 1 2.509-3.011l5.717 4.764Zm36.44-32.822v-7.358H60.856a1.96 1.96 0 0 1 0-3.92h21.331L92.685 2.073a1.96 1.96 0 0 1 2.772 2.772L84.385 15.917a1.963 1.963 0 0 1-1.386.574h-8.027v7.358h-3.92Zm-34.511-3.184H18.565a6.09 6.09 0 0 1-6.09-6.091v-.087a6.09 6.09 0 0 1 6.09-6.09h17.976a6.09 6.09 0 0 1 6.091 6.09v.087a6.091 6.091 0 0 1-6.091 6.091Z"
                  />
                </svg>

                <h4 class="fs-4">Modern equipment</h4>
                <p class="text-center text-white-50 p-element2">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />
                  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <br />
                  incididunt ut dolore facilisis.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 pb-5">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  data-name="Layer 1"
                  viewBox="0 0 68 85"
                  class="fontIconStyle section2-padding-left"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M39.87 62.78H9a5.73 5.73 0 0 1-5.72-5.72V11.12A5.73 5.73 0 0 1 9 5.4h5.18a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H9a3.73 3.73 0 0 0-3.72 3.72v45.94A3.73 3.73 0 0 0 9 60.78h30.87a1 1 0 1 1 0 2ZM49.79 35.42a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-23.3a3.73 3.73 0 0 0-3.72-3.72h-5.25a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h5.25a5.72 5.72 0 0 1 5.72 5.72v23.3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1Z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M38 10.88H16A2.88 2.88 0 0 1 13.22 8V4.86A2.82 2.82 0 0 1 16.07 2H38a2.76 2.76 0 0 1 2.78 2.86V8A2.82 2.82 0 0 1 38 10.88ZM16.07 4a.84.84 0 0 0-.85.86V8a.88.88 0 0 0 .85.85H38a.82.82 0 0 0 .82-.85V4.86A.78.78 0 0 0 38 4ZM13.67 22.41a1 1 0 0 1-.76-.34l-2-2.35a1 1 0 0 1 1.51-1.31l1.23 1.41L17 15.33a1 1 0 1 1 1.6 1.2L14.47 22a1 1 0 0 1-.76.4ZM13.67 33.79a1 1 0 0 1-.76-.34l-2-2.36a1 1 0 0 1 1.51-1.31l1.23 1.42L17 26.71a1 1 0 1 1 1.6 1.19l-4.09 5.49a1 1 0 0 1-.76.4ZM13.67 45.17a1 1 0 0 1-.76-.35l-2-2.35a1 1 0 1 1 1.51-1.31l1.23 1.42 3.35-4.5a1 1 0 1 1 1.6 1.2l-4.09 5.49a1 1 0 0 1-.76.4ZM13.67 56.54a1 1 0 0 1-.76-.34l-2-2.35a1 1 0 1 1 1.51-1.31L13.61 54 17 49.46a1 1 0 1 1 1.6 1.2l-4.09 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-.76.4ZM43.29 19.67H23.12a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h20.17a1 1 0 0 1 0 2ZM43.29 31.05H23.12a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h20.17a1 1 0 0 1 0 2ZM41.54 42.43H23.12a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h18.42a1 1 0 0 1 0 2ZM35.7 53.8H23.12a1 1 0 0 1 0-2H35.7a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M46.85 66a10.1 10.1 0 0 1-5.52-1.73A15.51 15.51 0 0 1 35 54.35a12.81 12.81 0 0 1 1.43-9.9 10.53 10.53 0 0 1 6.74-4.56 10.84 10.84 0 0 1 6.47.57 11 11 0 0 1 6.53-.57 10.55 10.55 0 0 1 6.75 4.56 12.88 12.88 0 0 1 1.43 9.91 15.55 15.55 0 0 1-6.37 9.91 9.75 9.75 0 0 1-7.33 1.54l-.65-.15-.42-.11-.3.09c-.22.06-.44.13-.67.17a8.18 8.18 0 0 1-1.76.19Zm-1.32-24.36a9.76 9.76 0 0 0-2 .21 8.53 8.53 0 0 0-5.47 3.69 10.93 10.93 0 0 0-1.16 8.4 13.54 13.54 0 0 0 5.51 8.65 7.63 7.63 0 0 0 5.82 1.26 3.65 3.65 0 0 0 .5-.13 5.33 5.33 0 0 1 .66-.17.87.87 0 0 1 .36 0 6.15 6.15 0 0 1 .82.2l.43.11a7.59 7.59 0 0 0 5.83-1.26 13.51 13.51 0 0 0 5.52-8.6 10.9 10.9 0 0 0-1.15-8.41 8.55 8.55 0 0 0-5.48-3.69 8.85 8.85 0 0 0-5.69.61 1 1 0 0 1-.88 0 8.19 8.19 0 0 0-3.62-.87Z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M49 40.9h-.29a1 1 0 0 1-.89-.64 6.36 6.36 0 0 1 .8-5.89 6.23 6.23 0 0 1 5.29-2.56 1 1 0 0 1 .89.62 6.3 6.3 0 0 1-.72 5.82A6.11 6.11 0 0 1 49 40.9Zm4.13-7.08a4.22 4.22 0 0 0-2.88 1.71 4.27 4.27 0 0 0-.75 3.34 4.14 4.14 0 0 0 2.94-1.77 4.43 4.43 0 0 0 .69-3.28Z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M49.59 43.86a1 1 0 0 1-1-.84 9.58 9.58 0 0 0-5.44-7.41 1 1 0 0 1 .91-1.78 11.58 11.58 0 0 1 6.5 8.87 1 1 0 0 1-.83 1.14Z"
                  />
                </svg>
                <h4 class="fs-4">Healthy nutrition plan</h4>
                <p class="text-center text-white-50 p-element2">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />
                  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <br />
                  incididunt ut dolore facilisis.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-dumbbell fontIconStyle"></i>
                <h4 class="fs-4">Proffesponal training plan</h4>
                <p class="text-center text-white-50 p-element2">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br />adipiscing elit,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor <br />
                  incididunt ut dolore facilisis.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-pulse fontIconStyle"></i>
                <h4 class="fs-4">Unique to your needs</h4>
                <p class="text-center text-white-50 p-element2">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br />adipiscing elit,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor <br />
                  incididunt ut dolore facilisis.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--section 2 end -->

    <!-- section3 start-->
    <section>
      <div class="section3 text-center">
        <div class="fade-in3">
          <h1 class="mb-5">REGISTRATION NOW TO GET MORE DEALS</h1>

          <h4 class="mb-5">WHERE HEALTH, BEAUTY AND FITNESS MEET.</h4>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg mt-2 button-section3"
          >
            APPOINTMENT
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- section3 end -->

    <!-- section4 start-->
    <section>
      <div class="section4">
        <div class="containerStyle">
          <div class="fade-in4">
            <div class="text-center pt-3">
              <h5 class="pb-2 pt-5 h5-section4">OUR PLAN</h5>
              <h3 class="pb-5 fw-medium" style="font-weight: 700">
                CHOOSE YOUR PRICING PLAN
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <!--- col-1 start -->
            <div
              class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 mx-lg-auto shadow-lg fade-in5 mx-xl-5 cards-container pb-lg-5"
            >
              <div class="text-center">
                <h3>Class drop-in</h3>
                <h1 class="cardPriceStyle">$39.0</h1>
                <p class="fw-medium">SINGLE CLASS</p>
                <ul class="pt-2 card-Detail-Style">
                  <li>Free riding</li>
                  <li>Unlimited equipments</li>
                  <li>Personal trainer</li>
                  <li>Weight losing classes</li>
                  <li>Month to mouth</li>
                  <li>No time restriction</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn card-Button-Style">
                    ENROLL NOW
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--col-1 end-->

            <!--col-2 start-->
            <div
              class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 mx-xl-5 shadow-lg pb-lg-5 fade-in6 cards-container mx-lg-auto"
            >
              <div class="text-center">
                <h3>12 Month unlimited</h3>
                <h1 class="cardPriceStyle">$99.0</h1>
                <p>SINGLE CLASS</p>
                <ul class="pt-2 card-Detail-Style">
                  <li>Free riding</li>
                  <li>Unlimited equipments</li>
                  <li>Personal trainer</li>
                  <li>Weight losing classes</li>
                  <li>Month to mouth</li>
                  <li>No time restriction</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn card-Button-Style shadow-lg">
                    ENROLL NOW
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col-2 end-->

            <!-- col-3 start-->
            <div
              class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 mx-xl-5 shadow-lg fade-in7 cards-container mx-lg-auto my-"
            >
              <div class="text-center">
                <h3>6 Month unlimited</h3>
                <h1 class="cardPriceStyle">$59.0</h1>
                <p class="fw-medium">SINGLE CLASS</p>
                <ul class="pt-2 card-Detail-Style">
                  <li>Free riding</li>
                  <li>Unlimited equipments</li>
                  <li>Personal trainer</li>
                  <li>Weight losing classes</li>
                  <li>Month to mouth</li>
                  <li>No time restriction</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn card-Button-Style">
                    ENROLL NOW
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- col-3 end-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- section4 end-->

    <!--section5 start -->

    <section>
      <div class="section5">
        <div>
          <div class="pt-3 mx-5">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="fade-in8 col-6">
                <h5 class="pb-2 pt-5 mx-5 h5-section5">OUR TEAM</h5>
                <h3 class="pb-5 mx-5 fw-bold float-start">
                  TRAIN WITH EXPERTS
                </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="fade-in9 col-6 pt-5">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-outline-warning mx-5 button-Section5-Style"
                >
                  APPOINTMENT
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="owl-carousel owl-theme fade-in10 w-75 container-section5-style"
          >
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/1.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/2.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/3.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/4.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/5.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/6.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/7.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/8.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/9.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
            <img
              src="../imageCarousel/10.png"
              alt=""
              class="imageCarousel shadow-lg"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- section5 end-->

    <!--section6 start-->

    <section>
      <div class="section6">
        <div class="row fade-in11">
          <div class="fs-5 col-4 text-center mt-5">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot iconStyle2"></i>
            <p class="pt-2 mb-2">333 Middle Winchendon Rd, Rindge NH 03461</p>
          </div>

          <div class="fs-5 col-4 mt-5 text-center">
            <i
              class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen-button iconStyle2"
              style="display: inline-block"
            ></i>
            <div>
              <p class="mt-2 info-Section6-Style">125-711-811</p>
              <p class="mt-2 p1-section6-Style info-Section6-Style">|</p>
              <p class="mt-2 info-Section6-Style">125-668-886</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="fs-5 col-4 mt-5 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope iconStyle2"></i>
            <p class="mt-2">Support.gymcenter@gmail.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--section6 end-->

    <!-- footer start -->
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-containter">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="fs-3 mx-5 ms-5">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-x-twitter mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube mx-3 text-white"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col fs-5">
              <a href="" class="text-decoration-none mx-2 text-white">Home</a>
              <a href="" class="text-decoration-none mx-2 Footer-NavStyle"
                >Service</a
              >
              <a href="" class="text-decoration-none mx-2 Footer-NavStyle"
                >About us</a
              >
              <a href="" class="text-decoration-none mx-2 Footer-NavStyle"
                >Contact us</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>

          <small class="fs-5 mb-3 text-white-50 mb-5">
            &copy copyright by Empower Fitness. all rights reserved
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!--footer end-->

    <!--my bootsrap js-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- my fontawesome js-->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bc6916a1d5.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- jquery cdn-->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>

    <!--owl carousel js file-->

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"
      integrity="sha512-gY25nC63ddE0LcLPhxUJGFxa2GoIyA5FLym4UJqHDEMHjp8RET6Zn/SHo1sltt3WuVtqfyxECP38/daUc/WVEA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>

    <!-- my owl carusel function -->
    <!-- Add a container for custom navigation dots -->
    <div class="custom-dots"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code you have shared works as you want it to work, could you describe your issue in more detail? what exactly are you wanting it to do?

Comment: @devin what I want is my first col to take the full viewport width, but  what I see is that it shares width with the second col , with  the last col taking  the full width , i want a triangle shape arrangement with  where the tip is pointing upward not downword, hope that made sense :)

Comment: <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

do you have that in the <head> tag?

Comment: And you only want this to be the case on smaller screens correct?

Comment: yes I have js cdn in my head tag, and yes  sir I only want this specific style on the smaller screens

Comment: post the head tag in your question

Comment: @devin , I did, add the whole html  my cards are  in section 4

Comment: put the bootstrap one at the bottom. the last link in the header tag

Comment: worked thank you so mush wonder what was the issue

Comment: the other css links you have are overwriting some of the bootstrap classes probably this owlcss

Comment: you can find out which one is the problem by moving the bootstrap one through the different link tags